# AS3 remove a node from a XML file by value of the child

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

So I have a xml file loaded up in my AS3 that looks like this:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
        value1
        </c>
    </b>
    <b>
    Value2
    </b>
</a>
```

Now let's say I'd like to remove the `<c></c>` by passing it "value1". 
By using the method explained here: [AS3 Delete child node from XML by child value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682641/as3-delete-child-node-from-xml-by-child-value) but it's only applied to the loaded xml and the actual file which is what I actually want. So I figured I should just save the file. But that didn't work out either, I got this error: "save is not a recognized method of the dynamic class XML." So I guess it doesn't work like that? And it doesn't look like this method is optimal for what I want to do.
So after more then 4 hours of looking for a solution I still have nothing. My teacher couldn't even help me, so please don't bin this one, I really need help. Thank you.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save()

Comment: The error you're talking about is often caused by other errors in the code (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841957/as3-toxmlstring-and-other-methods-not-recognized). It has happened to me before, see if there are any other errors first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified if you are using plain Flash or Adobe AIR... I am going to assume you are using plain Flash...And then I am going to assume you want to save the resulting, modified XML back into the file you loaded?

You need to look at the FileReference.save() method

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save()

BUT.. this will ask the user where they want to save the file, it wont silently overwrite the file you opened up initially.

And if overwriting the original file is what you are trying to do, then simply, you can't. Flash has all sorts of security restrictions that disallow you from doing such things.

If you are however talking about Adobe AIR, than that's different...